# 'figwheel' is not a task

Tags: clojurescript, figwheel

I was happily using figwheel all day. I terminated the process by entering `:cljs/quit`.

When I try to restart figwheel `lein figwheel`, I'm greeted with this message from leiningen:

```
'figwheel' is not a task. See 'lein help'
```

Running `lein help` lists many tasks I can perform, but figwheel is not among them.

Here's what my `project.clj` looks like (extra stuff elided):

```
(defproject myproject
 ...
:dependencies [...]
:plugins [[lein-environ "1.0.2"]
          [lein-cljsbuild "1.1.1"]
          [lein-asset-minifier "0.2.4"]]
...
:profiles {:dev {:dependencies [...
                                [lein-figwheel "0.5.0-6"]
                                ...]
                 :plugins [[lein-figwheel "0.5.0-6"]
                           ...]
                 :figwheel {...}}}
 ...)
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Verified I was in the correct directory
- Checked out all code changes made since the last successful figwheel start
- Added `[lein-figwheel "0.5.0-6"]` to the base `:plugins` vector (this sort of worked, but didn't recognize any of my profile-specific settings)
- Restarted my computer

Comment: Can you get rid of the error message by trial and error, so you can pinpoint where it seems to think `figwheel` is a task? Also a `lein clean` is always a good first step when in trouble like this. And then there's carefully checking all the `{ ` `}` - to make sure things are really grouped where you think they should be.

Comment: Alright, I've figured out the proximate cause. I use the `lein-environ` plugin and I had created a profiles.clj file. When I remove that file, `lein figwheel` works. I haven't quite figured out why this is the case, but at least I've got a workaround now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type [`lein help profiles`](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md#merging) to read all about profiles.  The problem in this case is caused by:

> Remember that if a profile with the same name is specified in multiple
>   locations, only the profile with the highest "priority" is picked – no
>   merging is done. The "priority" is – from highest to lowest –
>   profiles.clj, project.clj, user-wide profiles, and finally system-wide
>   profiles.

It's using the `:dev` in profiles.clj which doesn't have figwheel.  This is also why adding `lein-figwheel` to the base `:plugins` sort of helped, but doesn't use all your settings.

There's a straightforward solution suggested by the docs:

> If you need to enable personal overrides of parts of a profile, you can use a composite profile with common and personal parts - something like `:dev [:dev-common :dev-overrides]`; you would then have just `:dev-overrides {}` in project.clj and override it in profiles.clj.